# Bidirectional data flow in react js

Tags: reactjs

I saw that in many tutorials saying that react has unidirectional dataflow.Is there any possibilities to implement bi-directional data flow in reactjs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native bidirectional data flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816898/react-native-bidirectional-data-flow)

Comment: The uni-directional data flow is one of the selling point of react. You might wanna learn that first. But back to your question, what kind of API qualifies as bi-directional in your opinion? If you can describe that, i might give an answer.

Comment: sort of but not really? you can integrate a library that uses mutable/observable data structures instead of immutable flux/redux pattern. in the end you're still using `props` though https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a class component for example. Built-in react input component's API goes like:

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = { value: "foobar" }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={event => this.setState({ value: event.target.value })}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

We can build on top of that a custom component that has API behaving like a bi-directional component:

```
<Input model={state} propName="value" />
```

Here's how:

```
function Input(props) {
  const { model, propName } = props
  return <input
    value={model[propName]}
    onChange={event => model[propName] = event.target.value}
  />
}
```

Bad news is, this component alone can't do the magic, we need a bit of effort from the consumer side.

Let's make a class property decorator that casts the magic spell.

```js
function bidirectional(target, key) {
  Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
    get() {
      return this.state['__' + key]
    },
    set(val: any) {
      const privateKey = '__' + key
      if (!this.state) this.state = {}
      if (this.state.hasOwnProperty(privateKey)) {
        this.setState({ [privateKey]: val })
      } else {
        this.state[privateKey] = val
      }
      return true
    }
  })
}
```

Now you can do:

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
  @bidirectional
  value = "foobar"

  render() {
    return (
      <Input model={this} propName="value" />
    )
  }
}
```

Directly setting `this.value = "whatever"` also works, just like most bidirectional binding view-models out there.

> Personally I'm on the uni-directional side. Not saying bi-directional is wrong, but just thinking in the uni-directional fashion does pay off most of the time, like react people say, helps you reason about the app clearly.
>
> I do switch to bi-directional paradigm from time to time if I see fit. Like mentioned in comment, [MobX.js](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) is an excellent lib that extends the bi-directional idea way beyond, and works extremely well with react too. You should look into it.